# Exclude Digits from String using Regexp in MATLAB

Tags: regex, string, matlab, extract

Need to exclude Numbers from String and returns cell arrays of strings in MATLAB

```
e.g str = 'abc76.5_pol0.00_Ev0.3'

output {'abc','pol','Ev'}
```

String is not specific to 'abc' etc, it could be an char long

Comment: Could there be symbols too in the string, like - `'abc$$76.5_pol0.00_Ev0.3'` maybe?

Comment: No Symbols between letters and digits

Comment: Ok, between digits maybe or just anywhere in the string?

Comment: No, only '.' which actually a representation of decimal point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expression.

```
str = 'abc76.5_pol0.00_Ev0.3';
C = regexp(str, '[a-zA-Z]*', 'match');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that I found

```
output = regexp(str, '[^a-zA-Z]', 'split');
output(cellfun(@isempty,output)) = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `strsplit` with a `RegularExpression` option.

```
C = strsplit(str, '[^a-zA-Z]', 'DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression')
```

Comment: I believe strsplit is a function added in recent versions of MATLAB, am using R2010b and that function is not available

Comment: Your solution is quite similar to mine, but I don't understand why you get an empty cell at the end of `C`.